# Blanket.js coverage of dynamically loaded script file

Tags: javascript, blanket.js

I am using Blanket.js to test code coverage (with Jasmine, though I don't think this matters).  I have some scripts which are only loaded as needed.  These are loaded using jQuery's $.getScript() function.  How can I get Blanket.js to report coverage for  a dynamically loaded script?

I have tried loading the script by adding appending a script tag with the src to the end of the head (e.g.,  `$('<script/>', {src: (javascript path), 'data-cover': 'data-cover'}).appendTo('head');`).

I don't see any obvious functions to add a script within the blanket.js source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, here is a function that does what I wanted:

```
function addCoveredScript(url) {
    $('<script/>', {src: url}).appendTo('head');
    blanket.utils.cache[url] = {};
    blanket.utils.attachScript({url:url}, function (content) {
        blanket.instrument({inputFile: content, inputFileName: url},
                           function (instrumented) {
            blanket.utils.cache[url].loaded = true;
            blanket.utils.blanketEval(instrumented);
            blanket.requiringFile(url, true);
        });
   });
}
```

I don't know if there is a simpler way to do this, but it works.